# Error when trying to insert Formula to an ActiveCell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am writing a small script and I would like to insert a function to a specific cell. I have tried the following piece of code:

```
end_time = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Address
time_dif = "=TEXT(" + end_time + "-" + st_time + ";""[ωω]:μμ:δδ"")"
found = False

Workbooks("Template.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Address).Select

'Var = ActiveCell.formula
ActiveCell.formula = time_dif 'Var
```

The last line in the above code is throwing an error:
'Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error'

The time_dif variable contains the following string:

> "=TEXT($H$19-$H$13;"[ωω]:μμ:δδ")"

as seen in the local variables window

I have tried many different ways for the above to make it work but unfortunattely all of them failed.

What it actually worked is putting the exact same formula in another cell. Pause the execution an activate the cell with the formula. Put the formula in the variable Var and then move the activecell to the correct position and insert the variable Var value there.

```
Var = ActiveCell.formula 'Break point here / Run one step to take formula
ActiveCell.formula = Var 'Move to correct cell manually / Continue execution
```

Another thing I tried was removing the "=" from the formula and it puts the formula in the cell correctly as string.

Any advise or ideas about this?

Comment: Replace the semicolon with a comma in the formula string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VBE uses English syntaxes.
Try using a sub to get the English syntax, e.g:

```
Sub ert()
InputBox Prompt:=" ", Default:=Selection.Formula
End Sub
```

The correct answer thus will be

```
"=TEXT(" + end_time + "-" + st_time + ",""[ωω]:μμ:δδ"")"
```

with the "**,**" replacing the "**;**".

Comment: I don't think the problem is there. You can change "[ωω]:μμ:δδ" to "Number" {=TEXT(" + end_time + "-" + st_time + ";""Number"")} and get the same error. "[ωω]:μμ:δδ" is the same as "[hh]:mm:ss"

Comment: Did you try the "[hh]:mm:ss"? Believe me, one can have issues with regional settings, for me the lesson was decimal commas.

Comment: I have also said that you can take the same formula from another cell. Put in a variable and then from that other variable. The exact same string can be inserted in that cell. :/

Comment: Yes I have also tried "[hh]:mm:ss". I know. The regional settings can be a real pain sometimes!!

Comment: You were right, it works the way you described but in lieu of ";" you'll need to use ",". Regional settings...

Comment: Would you like to write the correct answer if you want me to accept it?

Comment: The method is as described in the original answer, I did place the correct formula in there as well. Thank you! The correct answer is sponsored by the Church of the Flying Pasta Monster.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` ?

Here you might change to include `Chr(34)`, in your string, but as it seems to display correctly, I don't think that's the problem...

```
"=TEXT(" & end_time & "-" & st_time & ";" & Chr(34) & "[hh]:mm:ss" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Comment: Nope it didn't make any difference. I Also tried your formula solution but I get the same error!